# StaggeredGridLayoutManager is showing images like GridLayoutManager

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I am trying to create `StaggeredGrid` with this code.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.userprofile_photos,container,false);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        photosRecycler=view.findViewById(R.id.userPhotos_recycler);
        layoutManager= new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
        photosRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        photosRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter=new fetchPhoto_Adapter();
        photosRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
```

Fragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/userPhotos_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter

```
public class fetchPhoto_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<fetchPhoto_Adapter.ViewHolder>{

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public fetchPhoto_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) viewGroup.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photogallery,viewGroup,false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(fetchPhoto_Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(ImageList.get(i)).apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop()).into(viewHolder.image);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
                return ImageList.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView image;
            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.UserProfile_photoThumb);
            }
        }

    }
```

Adapter Item Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


        <ImageView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/UserProfile_photoThumb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />
```

I tried to make it `StaggeredGrid` but with above code and with lots of modification like
setting image scaletype to fitxy,centercrop,center and changing height to wrap_content and modifying  Glide image loading code all showing same output. I wanted to make my `StaggeredGrid` Like below required output. Please help me out.

[image: Image Output/Required Output]

Comment: could you show me where you have created an instance of the adapter ?

Comment: @NitinTej `adapter=new fetchPhoto_Adapter();` inside onCreateView.

Comment: are you not going to pass any list to the adapter ?

Comment: @Nitin Tej he got the static data from ImageList inside the adapter

Comment: @HaiHack Exactly. I am setting static date to adapter

Answer (score 4):

Well I have achieved this in one of my projects, so I am here sharing you some code snippet over here. Try it and let me know.

```
class DemoActivity : ActivityBase() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo_activity)

    val layoutmanager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
    layoutmanager.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS
    rcv_staggered.layoutManager = layoutmanager
    rcv_staggered.setHasFixedSize(true)

    val listItem = ArrayList<DemoModel>()
    // This is dummy url for reference and in this image url I was 
    // getting image with different width and height
    val demoModel  = DemoModel("https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/400.jpg", "Title 1")
    val demoModel1 = DemoModel("https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/750/250.jpg", "Title 2")
    val demoModel2 = DemoModel("https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/500/250.jpg", "Title 3")
    val demoModel3 = DemoModel("https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/100/200.jpg", "Title 4")

    listItem.add(demoModel)
    listItem.add(demoModel1)
    listItem.add(demoModel2)
    listItem.add(demoModel3)

    rcv_staggered.adapter = DemoAdapter(listItem)
    }
}
```

---

Create recyclerView adapter same as we all do.

---

Load images using below snippet:

```
Glide.with(holder.img.context)
        .load(listItem[holder.adapterPosition].color)
        .placeholder(R.color.black_alpha_10)
        .into(holder.img)
```

---

And this is my item layout for recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

StaggeredGridLayoutManager Screenshot

[image: StaggeredGridLayoutManager Screenshot 1]

Comment: Your code giving me same output as i posted above.I also don't see any difference in my and your code. My code has some bug and it's a minor one which i can't catch

Comment: Okay I see, are you getting images in your URL with different height and width?

Comment: @androidXP: I have modified my code and added some more image urls for your reference, as I said I am getting images with different height and width in url.

Comment: I am setting static images to adapter and images are bit large in dimension but each image has different dimension from static web URL

Comment: Try removing this line apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop()) in your adapter

Comment: Adding placeholders worked for me. That was missing in my code

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `ImageView` inside `RelativeLayout`, it should be Ok

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/UserProfile_photoThumb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you make it? I reproduce what you did and just changes as above.

Answer (score 0):

I think their issues in glide code which you have used

Use this

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(imageList.get(i)).into(viewHolder.image);
```

Instead of this

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(ImageList.get(i)).apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop()).into(viewHolder.image);
```

> Also I have made some other changes in your code please check below example

Find the full code here

> MainActivity2 code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.flexbox.FlexDirection;
import com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager;
import com.google.android.flexbox.JustifyContent;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView photosRecycler;
    ArrayList<String> imageList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        photosRecycler = findViewById(R.id.userPhotos_recycler);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
        photosRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        photosRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        imageList.add("https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8FFo.jpg?s=328&g=1");
        imageList.add("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpdap.jpg?s=328&g=1");
        imageList.add("https://i.stack.imgur.com/73QY4.jpg");
        imageList.add("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpdap.jpg?s=328&g=1");
        imageList.add("https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8FFo.jpg?s=328&g=1");
        imageList.add("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpdap.jpg?s=328&g=1");
        imageList.add("https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8FFo.jpg?s=328&g=1");

        fetchPhoto_Adapter adapter = new fetchPhoto_Adapter(imageList, this);
        photosRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

> activity_main2 of layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/userPhotos_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> fetchPhoto_Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class fetchPhoto_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<fetchPhoto_Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context mContext;

    public fetchPhoto_Adapter(ArrayList<String> imageList, Context mContext) {
        this.imageList = imageList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public fetchPhoto_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photogallery, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(fetchPhoto_Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Glide.with(mContext).load(imageList.get(i)).into(viewHolder.image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.UserProfile_photoThumb);
        }
    }

}
```

> photogallery layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/UserProfile_photoThumb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Tried but no luck

Comment: @androidXP can you share you whole code as GitHub repository so I can try to reproduce the issue

Comment: Thanks for help but this is whole code if you want me to share

Comment: @androidXP I'm asking to share as a separate project on Github so I can reproduce the issue